# A Simple Chess Rebus

Tags: rebus, chess

*This is an entry to the [19th Fortnightly Topic Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-19-unconventional-tag-fusion?cb=1)*

Here is a relatively simple chess rebus:

[image]

Hint 1:

> The chessboard is inessential for interpreting the second image.

Hint 2:

> The first component is rather obvious, but the second is not.

Hint 3:

> **♀**

Comment: Is this an entry into the [19th fortnightly topic challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-19-unconventional-tag-fusion?cb=1)?

Comment: `The chessboard is inessential for interpreting the second image.`

Perhaps the second is not a knight, but simply a horse?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon, you are on the right horse track!

Comment: The black knight's square... does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp, the square d5 has nothing to do with it. I would focus on the second image assuming something obvious about the first.

Comment: @silenus: generally, puzzles should be solvable without requiring info in the hints.  I don't see how it would have been possible to solve this without hint 3, as making the intuitive leap from "the white knight looks different" to "oh, it must be female" is pretty unlikely (especially when in the original image the two were identical save for their color). Just a note for future puzzles.  This one took us in a lot of interesting directions, that's for sure!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> Nightmare

Because

> (K)night + mare

Hints 1 and 2

> The knight part is obvious but the mare bit is not.

Hint 3

> A mare is the female of a horse.

Comment: Nicely done! :)

Answer (score 4):

It is...

> [Batman & Robin: Dark Knight Vs. White Knight](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401233732)

Because

> Batman is the Dark Knight, and the White Knight is self-explanatory.

Comment: That's not what I intended but it certainly fits! +1

Comment: two wrong answers that fit, is a hint this may be too broad :)

Comment: I think you're right. I altered the image to narrow possible solutions and to hint that the chessboard is not essential for interpreting the second piece.

Comment: Haha, awesome, +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Could the answer be

> the word "definite"?

Because

> the black knight is on d5 ("defy"), and the second image is a knight - add them together, and it sounds like "definite".

Answer (score 3):

Is it simply ...

> A dark knight on (or with) a white horse ?

Or possibly, a more specific case:

> **Pestilence** (one of the 4 Horsemen of the Apocalypse)
>  usually portrayed as a dark armored figure on a white horse

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Two (k)nights left? (Pretty self-explanatory)

Comment: That's not what I intended but it certainly fits! +1

Answer (score 2):

Is it just

> Dark horse

Because

> We have a black knight but the second knight looks very much more like a horse

Comment: If I was going to create the "dark horse" rebus I would have showed a *single* black knight! ;) But maybe that the symbols look different should clue you into something.